# How to use xml file field in Jetpack compose

Tags: xml, webview, android-jetpack-compose, editor

I have old xml. Now I want to migrate it to Jetpack Compose.
I migrated all fields but I have one custom field in mu xml file:

```
com.activity.compose.MyRichEditor
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textLongMessage|textAutoCorrect"
                android:id="@+id/message_view"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:ignore="WebViewLayout" />
```

It is implementation of RichTextEditor (editable webview).

How can I insert such field MyRichEditor to compose view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AndroidView`.

```
AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier,
    factory = { context ->
        MyRichEditor(context).apply {

        }
    },
    update = {

    },
)
```

Comment: but how can I get text from it from viewmodel?

Comment: I couldn't understand its connection with the question you asked.

Comment: No, MyRichEditor its an editor. How can I get from viewmodel class users input. like viewmodel.getMyRichEditorTextInput?

Comment: you can add `MyRichEditor`'s change listeners in the `apply` scope, keep them in a state in the `viewModel` and trigger them.

Comment: could you write it? Will it recompose all the time then other states of this composable view change they state?